# I need regex replacement

Tags: regex

I need regex replacement to emphasis fist letter of my movies list...

Sample:

I would like to get from this list

```
Camp (2004)
Can't Hardly Wait (1998)
Candy (2006)
Canyons, The (2014)
Daddy Day Care (2003)
Daddy and Them (2002)
Daddy's Home (2016)
Eating Out: All You Can Eat (2010)
Eddie the Eagle (2016)
Eddie (1997)

to get this

Camp (2004)
Can't Hardly Wait (1998)
Candy (2006)
Canyons, The (2014)

D

Daddy Day Care (2003)
Daddy and Them (2002)
Daddy's Home (2016)

E

Eating Out: All You Can Eat (2010)
Eddie the Eagle (2016)
Eddie (1997)
```

I tried something like this

^(\w).+\r\n^[^$1].+

to find two lines that start with different letter (which is main issue), but it doesn't work.

Can anyone help?

Comment: regex differs slightly from language to language. What's yours?

Comment: Maybe [this will work](https://regex101.com/r/YPnMl7/1)?

Comment: I don't know, I'm using Notepad ++ , but list of movies is updated regularly so I need this replacement to avoid annoying manual edit.

Comment: In NPP, use `^(\w)(.*)(\R)(?!\1)(?=\w)` and replace with `$1$2$3$3$1$3$3`

Comment: it almost that , but it puts letter A above movies that begins with letter B etc....Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry I made correction at my question it should start with letter and then follows movies that begins with that letter , please Wiktor tweak your replacement anyway I can try by your idea later...thanks muchly!

Comment: To have the first letter: https://regex101.com/r/rEUV6g/1

Comment: or better with melpomene approach: https://regex101.com/r/vsOWEX/1

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work in Notepad ++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to achieve that using Sublime Text.

You could try:

```
^(.)(.*)\n(?!\1)
```

Replacing to:

```
$1$2\n\n$1\n\n
```

**Edit** (because the question was edited: letter prefixing instead of postfixing):

Again with Sublime Text, I did:

```
^(.)(.*)\n(?!\1)(.)
```

Replaced by:

```
$1$2\n\n$3\n\n$3
```

Comment: Well in notepad ++ \r have to be added and then it work. So it looks like ^(.)(.*)\r\n(?!\1)(.) with $1$2\n\n$3\n\n$3...and would you believe me that I tried same thing with negative assertion a day ago and it didn't work!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a search/replace command that works in vim:

```
:%s/^\(.\).*\n\%(\1.*\n\)*/\1\r\r&\r/g
```

Instead of trying to find a line that doesn't start with some letter, we just match as many lines as possible that do start with the same letter.

Comment: I made correction in my question it should crop letter then below goes movies that begins with that letter.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all, but I see another issue right now, it make difference in capital letters and small letters and it wrongly break list and insert that letter.

Example:

```
...
...
I

Icon
IP Man

i

iPad

I

Iron Man
Ireland
....
...
```

but OK I will fix it later manually.

I prefer solution made by Wiktor Stribiżew

`^(\w)(.*)(\R)(?!\1)(?=\w)` replace with `$1$2$3$3$1$3$3`

but it needs to be tweaked to right letter precede movies that begins with that letter according to my edited question.

Thanks to all!!